# Azure DevOps OAuth WorkItemSnapshot query - can I do date arithmetic?

Tags: azure-devops, date-arithmetic

I'm running an OAuth query against WorkItemSnapshot where I want to query item snapshots between the Iteration/EndDate and the Iteration/EndDate **+ 1 day**.

Is it possible to do date arithmetic in these types of queries? I can't find an example in the docs, but am positive the functionality must exist!

```
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/MyOrg/MyProject/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItemSnapshot?
 $apply=filter(
 WorkItemType eq 'User Story'
 and startswith(Area/AreaPath,'MyProject')
 and DateValue gt Iteration/EndDate
 and DateValue lt DATEADD(day,1,Iteration/EndDate)
 and DateValue ge 2021-06-01Z
 )
 /groupby(
 (Iteration/IterationPath,Area/AreaPath,WorkItemType,State,DateValue),
 aggregate($count as Count, StoryPoints with sum as TotalStoryPoints)
 )
```